# Sequences that sum up to possible generalization of Euler or up/down numbers (A000111)

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, recurrences

Let $a(n,m,k)$ be an integer sequence with e.g.f.
$$A(x)=\operatorname{exp}\left(x + m\int\int (A(x))^k \, dx \, dx\right)$$
I don't know much about integrals, so here's a concrete example:

- $a(n,1,3)$ - [A234239](https://oeis.org/A234239)

Let
$$\ell(n)=\left\lfloor\log_2 n\right\rfloor$$
$$f(n)=n-2^{\ell(n)}$$
$$\operatorname{wt}(2n+1)=\operatorname{wt}(n)+1, \operatorname{wt}(2n)=\operatorname{wt}(n), \operatorname{wt}(0)=0$$
$$T(n,k)=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}\right\rfloor\operatorname{mod}2$$
Here $f(n)$ is the same as $n$ without the most significant bit, $\operatorname{wt}(n)$ is the binary weight of $n$ or the number of $1$'s in the binary expansion of $n$ and $T(n,k)$ is the $(k+1)$-th bit from the right side in the binary representation of $n$.

Let $b(n,m,k)$ be an integer sequence such that
$$b(n,m,k)=m(\ell(n)-2\operatorname{wt}(n)+3)b(f(n),m,k)+\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\ell(n)} k(1-T(n,j))b(f(n)+2^j(1-T(n,j)),m,k)$$

Let $s(n,m,k)$ be an integer sequence such that
$$s(n,m,k)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{2^n-1}b(j,m,k)$$
I conjecture that
$$s(n,m,k)=a(n+1,m,k)$$
Here is the PARI prog to verify this conjecture:

```
s(n, m, k) = my(v, v1); v=vector(2^n, i, 0); v[1]=1; v1=vector(n+1, i, 0); v1[1]=1; for(i=1, #v-1, my(L=logint(i, 2), A=i-2^L); v[i+1]=m*(L - 2*hammingweight(i) + 3)*v[A+1] + k*sum(j=0, L, my(B=bittest(i, j)); (B==0)*v[A + 2^j*(B==0) + 1])); for(i=1, n, v1[i+1]=v1[i]+sum(j=2^(i-1)+1, 2^i, v[j])); v1
a(n, m, k) = local(A=1+x); for(i=1, n, A=exp(x + m*intformal(intformal(A^k + x*O(x^n))))); n!*polcoeff(A, n)
test(n, m, k) = s(n, m, k)==vector(n+1, i, a(i, m, k))
```

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: Note that unless $k = 2m$, $$A(x)^k = \frac{2(2m-k)(m-k+\alpha) e^{\alpha x}}{((m-k+\alpha) e^{\alpha x} + m)^2}$$ with $\alpha = \sqrt{k^2 - 2km}$

Comment: @PeterTaylor, thank you for comment! Nice observation! Could you tell me how to calculate the square root on PARI so that when extracting the coefficient from the function, an integer result is obtained? I tried c^(1/2) but for large $k$ it still turns out to be a decimal fraction.

Comment: There [does appear to be support for number fields in PARI](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html/General_number_fields.html), but I don't use PARI and I don't know whether that page contains sufficient information on how to calculate with elements of number fields.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, thank you again! I'm too lazy to figure it out myself, so I'll try to ask around from familiar experts.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, if you substitute your result into the original formula, is it possible to get a closed form?

Comment: Just take $k$th roots. You can do it by substituting and doing a lot of algebra, but it ends up in the same place.